# How can I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I put in a question where I try to learn FPGA and I got downvoted for no reasoned mentioned. Could you help me improve the question since it is not a bogus question and not a bad question since it is about upgrading from SOPC to QSys in Quartus II.

[How to upgrade a Quartus II project from SOPC to QSys?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79265/please-help-me-resolve-my-system-errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One immediate thing that comes to mind is that I see you've posted the project files as a comment at a later point. You may have copped a few downvotes for a problem not easy to repeat without a significant effort so that would be worth editing into the question. Remember if that was the case their downvotes may be "locked in" because you haven't edited the question since.

Another thing is that on Stack Overflow it's accepted that there's no need to include tag names in the title. Rightly or wrongly that doesn't seem to go down well here, so maybe a title such as "Errors upgrading SOPC VHDL project to Quartus II" would come across better.

Finally it might be considered to be too broad, although personally I don't know enough about the Altera tools to know if that's the case or if all the problems are likely to stem for a few simple problems. Maybe a description of a few things you've tried without success would make it look a bit less like a "port my code" question.

Comment: I've gotten an extensive answer now that I accept. I can also try downgrading to Quartus II v12 and use SOPC instead of QSys but I think best would be to use the latest version.